# Cryptoki dll causing application to crash

Tags: c#, smartcard

I'm using cryptoki in a C# app. The problem I have is the following:
I initialize cryptoki using the following code:

```
public static bool InitializeCryptoki(string criptokilib)
{
    if (cryptoki != null)
        throw new PdfSignException(PdfSignExceptionCode.PDF_EXCEPTION_NOT_FINALIZED);
    try
    {
        cryptoki = new Cryptoki(criptokilib);
        if (cryptoki.Initialize() == 0)
        {
            isInitialized = true;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    catch (CryptokiException ex)
    {
        Log.Log(log, LogState.ERROR, UserId, "Initialize", null, ex.Message);
        return false;
    }
}
```

**criptokilib value is equal to "eTPKCS11.dll".**

After cryptoki is initialized, I check if at least one card reader exists using the following code:

```
public static bool HasCardReaders
{
    get
    {
        if (cryptoki == null)
            throw new PdfSignException(PdfSignExceptionCode.PDF_EXCEPTION_NOT_INITIALIZED);
        return cryptoki.Slots.Count != 0;
    }
}
```

- When running the app in debug mode from the compiler (VS 2012), an error message is displayed (no app crash) saying that no card reader has been detected.
- When running the app outside the compiler (VS 2012) - by double clicking the exe in debug folder, my application crashes. Looking at the log files, sometimes the app crashes while initializing cryptoki, and sometimes the app crashes while checking if at least one card reader exists.

In debug mode, I discovered that **cryptoki.Slots[i].Token** throws error n. 224 - this error means that no token is present. Can this error cause my app to crash? Do you have any idea how to overcame this issue?

Thank you very much,
Gica G.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that upgrading to the last NCryptoki.dll resolves the issue.

However I still didn't understood why that error was causing my app to crash.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (cryptoki != null)
```

This looks wrong. That should read:

```
if (cryptoki == null)
```

Comment: I need to be sure that if cryptoki was used before, that session was finalized, so cryptoki has to be null.

Comment: If it's *always* `null`, why pass it as a parameter in the first place? Especially since you pass it on.

Comment: @nvoigt It looks like the method is intended to be called on an object reference of his class, which means that the `cryptoki` variable in the class could be instantiated already when the method is called, but shouldn't be.

Comment: `cryptoki = new Cryptoki(criptokilib);` ? You made sure that you *always* pass `null` in this line. Either this is an error, or you should just pass `null` and scrap the parameter.

Comment: @nvoigt You got it wrong. I pass as parameter cryptokilib, which is equal with "eTPKCS11.dll".
I need to be sure that cryptoki is null, not cryptokilib.